# You have an error in your SQL syntax. Query Error

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

```
$ProjectName = $_POST['ProjectName'];
$ProjectModule = $_POST['ProjectModule'];
$ProjectDescription = $_POST['ProjectDescription'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO database (ProjectName,ProjectModule,ProjectDescription) VALUES (". mysql_real_escape_string($ProjectName) .",".mysql_real_escape_string($ProjectModule).",".mysql_real_escape_string($ProjectDescription).")";
```

I'm facing below error.

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'database (ProjectName,ProjectModule,ProjectDescription) VALUES
>   (sankaran,sankar' at line 1

What's the solution please say me

Comment: Are you kidding me, you have a table name called `database` ? Check the manual for mysql reserved keywords.

Comment: `database` is  a keyword in SQL. either change your table name to another or try using backtick(`) to wrap table name

Comment: \`database\` instead of database

Comment: **Warning**:  You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) which has been **removed** entirely from the latest version of PHP. You should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).

Comment: You should really name your table something other than ````database```` as has already been pointed out (or escape it) but if you get a syntax error in the SQL query then look at the query. Just do a ````echo $sql;```` and you will see that your query is built together without any quotes around the strings. I urge you to read up on your SQL and PHP MySQL before proceeding with building an application.

Answer (score 1):

`database` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and needs to be escaped by backticks.

Actually you should rename your table since `database`  says nothing about the content of a table.